# Enabling Email Address or Phone Number as the user identifier in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We are currently in the process of migrating one of our applications to Azure AD B2C. In the existing application, users are able to log in using either their email or phone number as their user identifier. I am seeking information on whether this same functionality is possible with B2C.

[image]

We are currently using policy file based configuration. Is this possible to achieve in Azure AD B2C?

I would appreciate any documentation or resources you may have on how to achieve this.

Comment: Yes, Azure AD B2C supports using both email and phone number as user identifiers for authentication.

Answer (score 1):

> I am seeking information on whether this same functionality is possible with B2C.

Yes, it is possible to allow users to log in using both their email and phone number as their user identifier in Azure AD B2C.

You can follow below steps to create two sign-in policies, one for email and one for phone number.

1. Go to **Azure Portal** >search for and select **Azure AD B2C** > **Identity providers** > **Local Account**.

[image]

2. Create user attribute for **Phone number** as below.

   **Select user attributes > Add.**

[image]

3. Create a **User flow** as below.

**Select User flows > New user flow > Signup and Sign in.**

[image]

4. Add **Phone number** attribute to user flow as below.

**Azure AD B2C > User flows > B2C_1_Signupand-Signin > User attributes.**

[image]

5. Run the **user flow** as below.

[image]

6. Once ran the **user flow** application will display below screen.

[image]

Refer:  [Create user flows and custom policies in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows?pivots=b2c-user-flow) for more details about Azure AD B2C Authentication.